# save the current items on qwidget as image

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying draw some rhombuses with random colors in a `QWidget`. And i want to save the current `QWidget` as image. I use such code to do this:

> ```
> QPixmap pixmap(this->size());
> this->render(&pixmap);
> pixmap.save("test.png");
> ```

The problem is that the `render()` seems to call `paintEvent` again, and the `paintEvent` will draw the rhombuses with new random colors, so that i always get a different Image saved compared to the image displayed. Can someone tell me how to save the current `QWidget`? Thanks in advance.

Code for drawing rhombuses:

> void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
>
> ```
> QPainter painter(this);
> QRect background(0,0,this->geometry().width(),this->geometry().height());
> painter.setBrush( QBrush( Qt::white ) );
> painter.setPen( Qt::NoPen );
> //QBrush bbrush(Qt::black,Qt::SolidPattern);
> painter.drawRect(background);
>
> int width = this->geometry().width();
> int height = this->geometry().height();
> //draw rectangles
> int rec_size=64;
> int rows=0;
> int cols=0;
>
> rows=floor((double)height/(double)rec_size);
> cols=floor((double)width/(double)rec_size);
>
> QPointF points[4]; //    QRect rec(0,0,rec_size,rec_size);
>
> for (int i=0;i<floor(rows);i++){
>     for (int j=0;j<floor(cols);j++){
>        painter.setBrush( QBrush( colors[rand() % color_size] ) );
>      
>
>        //QPainter painter(this);
>        points[0] = QPointF(rec_size*(j),rec_size*(i+0.5));
>        points[1] = QPointF(rec_size*(j+0.5),rec_size*(i));
>        points[2] = QPointF(rec_size*(j+1),rec_size*(i+0.5));
>        points[3] = QPointF(rec_size*(j+0.5),rec_size*(i+1));
>
>        painter.drawPolygon(points, 4);
>
>     }
> }
> painter.end();
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Correct: draw what you need to `QImage`, and draw `QImage` on paint event.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a class member variable of boolean type to check in the `paintEvent` whether a random color should be used. Also a variable to save the index of the last color used is necessary:

```
bool isRandom;
int lastColor;
```

The `paintEvent` should be like :

```
void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {

   ...

   if(isRandom)
   {
       lastColor = rand() % color_size;
       painter.setBrush( QBrush( colors[lastColor] ) );
    }
    else
       painter.setBrush( QBrush( colors[lastColor] ) );

    ...

}
```

The variable has true when drawing the widget regularly. When you want to save it's image, assign the variable to false, save the image and assign it to true again :

```
isRandom = false;

QPixmap pixmap(this->size());
this->render(&pixmap);
pixmap.save("test.png");

isRandom = true;
```